# fade out on anchor click and fade in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if it is possible to make fadings between two HTML-Documents.
I have a few HTML-Pages but let's make an example with two of them.

```
index.html, jobs.html
```

On both I have a menu with `<a>` buttons. What I want to do is:

I click on `<a href="jobs.html" id="jobs">Jobs</a>` and `index.html` (which I am currently on) fades out and `jobs.html` fades in. Something like fading between `div`s but with a whole HTML document.

Any helps is much appreciated.

Comment: are you loading this jobs.html by ajax?

Comment: nope! I'm making a page-switch!

Comment: [This looks cool](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/)

Comment: @supersize fade the content in on document ready and fade it out when the user leaves the page. If you want for a specific page then filter the url or add classes do body, etc

Comment: @musefan can't use css3! but thanks, I will remember this :)

Comment: @Spokey how do I call a page-leave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Hide the body using css.
2. Fade in the body
3. Click a button and grab its ID
4. Fade out the body
5. Navigate to the new url

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            display: none;
        }
        .myBtn{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('body').fadeIn();
            $('.myBtn').click(function(){
                url = $(this).attr('id') + '.html';
                $('body').fadeOut(function(){
                    window.location = url;
                });     
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>index.html</h1>
    <div class="myBtn" id="index">index</div>
    <div class="myBtn" id="jobs">jobs</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dp4Hy/

PS. obviously the fiddle won't work, as you're trying to navigate to a new page, but you can still see the fade in at the beginning, and fade out when you click a button. Just need this script included for all pages to use.

Comment: the fadeOut does not work on firefox! On Chrome and Safari it looks nice!

Comment: I will update the above demo, but all you'd need to do, is put the part where it switches the window.location in a callback function of the fadeOut.

Comment: My bad, put the url = $(this).attr('id') + '.html'; before the fadeOut.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line, this is not possible without some kind of pre-loading and interaction with a server side component

I would personally recommend PJAX. http://pjax.heroku.com/ It allows you not only catch an event and load a document based on the event, it updates the browser state, url, title, the back button works, etc.

example sites that use it to accomplish similiar behavior 
http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1716958-the-top-10-fantasy-qbs-for-2013
http://reciperehab.com/blog/post/the-6-best-salads-for-spring

*disclaimer, I did the second one...

Comment: I know ajax would be the most elegant way but I do want to keep it as simple as possible. Just jquery! Thanks anyways, this will help me sometime!

Answer (score 1):

Create your anchor tag and set a javascript onclick event. Call your fadeOut() function (which i've pasted below) You'll want it to fade out when you click, and when the next page loads, you'll want it to fade in:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HmGap/3/

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){fadeIn('body')};
</script>

<div id="body">
    Content <br /><br />
    <a onClick="fadeOut('body')" style="cursor:pointer">Click Me to Fade Out</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

//fadeEffects

```
var fade_in_from = 0;
var fade_out_from = 10;

function fadeIn(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    target.style.display = "block";
    var newSetting = fade_in_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    // opacity ranges from 0 to 1
    fade_in_from++;
    if(fade_in_from == 10){
        target.style.opacity = 1;
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_in_from = 0;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeIn(\''+element+'\')',100);
}
function fadeOut(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    var newSetting = fade_out_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    fade_out_from--;
    if(fade_out_from == 0){
        target.style.opacity = 0;
        target.style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_out_from = 10;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeOut(\''+element+'\')',100);
    window.location.href = "link.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you can append the html in DIV (like you know), or you can use iframes, to manager the fade of the iframe tag