# Fade In/out div elements when a # anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get different divs to fade in and out when I click a image with a `<a href>` in it and # to make it fade in and out. I can not get it to fade in and out no matter what I try.  This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var state = $(this).val();
        $("#" + state).toggleClass("overlay");
    });


    $('#triggerButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#firstscreen').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $('#casualshirt').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 #background {
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     position: relative;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 600px;
     height: 800px;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index:0;
 }
 #Background {
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 600px;
     height: 800px;
     z-index:1;
 }
 #Layer1 {
     left: 24px;
     top: 16px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 285px;
     height: 762px;
     z-index:2;
 }
 #Rectangle1 {
     left: 34px;
     top: 59px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 260px;
     height: 512px;
     z-index:3;
 }
 #Layer6 {
     left: 339px;
     top: 541px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 98px;
     height: 116px;
     z-index:4;
 }
 #Shirts {
     left: 391px;
     top: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 133px;
     height: 42px;
     z-index:5;
 }
 #Layer2 {
     left: 258px;
     top: 138px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 260px;
     height: 139px;
     z-index:6;
 }
 #Layer4 {
     left: 252px;
     top: 315px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 197px;
     height: 188px;
     z-index:7;
 }
 #Layer5 {
     left: 498px;
     top: 366px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 62px;
     height: 86px;
     z-index:8;
 }
 #Layer7 {
     left: 407px;
     top: 492px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 174px;
     height: 165px;
     z-index:9;
 }
 #Layer8 {
     left: 366px;
     top: 685px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 55px;
     height: 108px;
     z-index:10;
 }
 #Layer9 {
     left: 490px;
     top: 670px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 98px;
     height: 101px;
     z-index:11;
 }
 #Layer10 {
     left: 221px;
     top: 642px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 130px;
     height: 117px;
     z-index:13;
 }
 #Layer3 {
     left: 368px;
     top: 95px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 260px;
     height: 182px;
     z-index:14;
 }
 .overlay {
     display: none;
 }
 #map {
     /*right: -780px; removed for demo purposes */
     width: 285px;
     height: 762px;
     padding: 29px;
     background: url(http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer1.png) no-repeat;
 }
 #station_A {
     top: 0%;
     /* whatever you like */
     left: 0%;
     /* whatever you like */
     position: absolute;
 }
 #station_B {
     top: 0%;
     /* whatever you like */
     left: 0%;
     /* whatever you like */
     position: absolute;
 }
 input[type=checkbox] {
     display:none;
 }
 input[type=checkbox] + label {
     background-image: url('/images/shirt_sprites.png');
     display: block;
     height: 72px;
     padding: 0;
     width: 72px;
 }
 #paradisetanktop + #paradisetanktop_s {
     background-position: 72 0;
 }
 #paradisetanktop:checked + #paradisetanktop_s {
     background-position: 0 0;
 }
 #bandanatop + #bandanatop_s {
     background-position: 0 0;
 }
 #bandanatop:checked + #bandanatop_s {
     background-position: 0 0;
 }
 button {
     background-image: url(images/Next.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
     /* put the height and width of your image here */
     height: 27px;
     width: 55px;
     border: none;
 }
 button span {
     display: none;
 }
 #casualshirt {
     width: 384px;
     height: 609px;
     left: 350px;
     background: url('http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/casualtop.png') no-repeat;
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     z-index: 15;
 }
 #firstscreen {
     width: 384px;
     height: 609px;
     left: -30px;
     position: absolute;
     background: url('http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/firstscreen.png') no-repeat;
     z-index: 12;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="firstscreen"></div>
  <div id="background">
  <div id="Background"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Background.png"></div>
  <div id="Layer1"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer1.png"></div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="Rectangle1"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Rectangle1.png"></div>
  <div id="shirts">
      <div id="Shirts"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Shirts.png"></div>
      <div id="Layer2"><a href="#" id="triggerbutton"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer2.png"></div>
      <div id="Layer4"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer4.png"></div>
      <div id="Layer5"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer5.png"></div>
      <div id="Layer6"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer6.png"></div>
      <div id="Layer7"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer7.png"></div>
      <div id="Layer9"><a href="#" id="btn"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Next.png"></a></div>
      <div id="Layer10"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer10.png"></div>
      <div id="Layer3"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/Layer3.png"></div>
      <div id="casualshirt"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="colors"></div>
  </div>
```

I've researched this thoroughly and can not get it to work.

UPDATE: I did Include Fiddle but it got removed here is the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLrf1cLz/1/)

UPDATE: Updated  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLrf1cLz/2/) with fixed for the id.

Comment: Please avoid posting walls of code. You are more likely to attract good answers if you post a minimal representation of your problem, with as little irrelevant bloat as possible. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: possible duplicate of [fade out on anchor click and fade in href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019183/fade-out-on-anchor-click-and-fade-in-href)

Comment: Can you give an example of what should fade out / fade in?  Your code is complex.  Also, note that `#triggerbutton` (in markup) and `triggerButton` (in js) are not the same.

Comment: Sujay, I referred to that post in my research and did everything it suggested and yet my code does not work.

Comment: gibberish, what should fade out is the #firstscreen then #casualshirt should fade in with the shirt image.

Comment: Notice that the src reference for the #casualshirt does not exist: http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/casualtop.png

Comment: Just give us a fiddle instead of all this messy code!

Comment: gibberish, I have added a fiddle. also the casualtop.png was in the wrong folder. I moved it to the right folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove trigger click function outside of document load. Because you added jquery lib inside body element.

Also you can fade out and fade in target parent div element for flashing thing.

```
$(document).on('click', '#triggerButton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#firstscreen').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $(e.toElement.parentElement).fadeOut().delay(200).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLrf1cLz/4/

UPDATE 1:

CSS:

```
#casualshirt {
    top: 100px;
    width: 384px;
    height: 609px;
    background: url('http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/images/casualtop.png') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 123123;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#triggerButton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#firstscreen').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $(e.toElement.parentElement).fadeOut();
        $('#casualshirt').fadeIn()
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLrf1cLz/8/

Comment: This works how I would like it however instead of fading out the icon you click and fading it back in. I want it to fade in another div.

Comment: What is the name of the another div?

Comment: ,#casualshirt is the 2nd div.

Comment: #casualshirt div position is invalid, because is out of html page and even style applied as display:block, div will not be shown.